# How to create nested lets in rspec?

Tags: rspec

Is it possible to modify an existing `let` variable, such as adding an entry to a hash:

```
describe 'my spec' do
  let(:var) { { a: 1, b: 2 } }
  let(:foo) { bar(var) }

  context 'when c is defined' do
    let(:var) { var.merge c: 3 }  # This does not work because it will be evaluated recursively
    # ... actual tests using foo ... 
  end

end
```

I want `var` to be `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`.

Comment: Did you find the solution you were looking for?  What did your spec end up looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you created a circular dependency, it won't work.

I think the best solution is to set the `var` content static on contexts that it needs to be changed:

```
...
let(:var) { { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } }
...
```

If you really need to merge the hash with something else, the following workaround will do the trick, changing the existing hash in place with the `before` callback:

```
describe 'my spec' do
  let(:var) { { a: 1, b: 2 } }
  let(:foo) { bar(var) }

  context 'when c is defined' do
    before { var.merge! c: 3 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Unfortunately, now `before` is used which is a bit of a performance loss, and mixing `let` and `before` although they are used for the same purpose makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested RSpec contexts to test the behaviour of different parameters, you can partially override the parent parameters by merging the changed parameters into `super()` in your `let(:foo)` block:

```
describe 'My::Class' do
  let(:foo) do
    {
      'some_common_param' => 'value'
      'role'              => 'default',
    }
  end

  context 'with role => web' do
    let(:foo) do
      super().merge({ 'role' => 'web' })
    end

    it { should compile }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just re-define `var` in each `context` in the form it is needed in.  `foo` is evaluated lazily so it will use the appropriate version of `var` defined in each `context` when it is eventually called in the `it` block:

```
describe 'my spec' do
  let(:foo) { bar(var) }

  context 'when c is defined' do
    let(:var) { { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } }

    it 'returns some result with c' do
      expect(foo).to eq('bar with c') # or whatever it returns
    end 
  end

  context 'when d is defined' do
    let(:var) { { a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 } }

    it 'returns some result with d' do
      expect(foo).to eq('bar with d') # or whatever it returns
    end  
  end
end
```

**Edit**: if you *really* want nested `let`s, then I'd say either go with [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075229/567863), or if the base definition of `var` won't be tested in the specs, then put it in a separate `let` statement (if it is tested, then you'll get unavoidable repetition as per the final example):

```
describe 'my spec' do
  let(:base_var) { { a: 1, b: 2 } }
  let(:foo) { bar(var) }

  context 'when c is defined in var' do
    let(:var) { base_var.merge(c: 3) }

    it 'returns some result with c' do
      expect(foo).to eq('bar with c') # or whatever it returns
    end 
  end

  context 'when d is defined in var' do
    let(:var) { base_var.merge(d: 4) }

    it 'returns some result with d' do
      expect(foo).to eq('bar with d') # or whatever it returns
    end  
  end

  context 'when no changes made from base_var to var' do
    let(:var) { base_var }

    it 'returns some result from just bar' do
      expect(foo).to eq('just bar') # or whatever it returns
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a way to circumvent the problem. The downside is that this spec is not DRY, because `{a: 1, b: 2}` is repeated.

Comment: I would counter by saying I think that DRYness, although a virtue in application code itself, takes a backseat to readability in specs.  I think being clear and succinct _upfront_ about what methods/parameters are under test can help reduce cognitive overhead.  Imagine if you had multiple `context`s for `'my spec'` (with perhaps some of them nested), and in each `context` going down you `merge`d some elements into the `var` hash to eventually complete to your final data under test in the `it` block: you'd have to keep a mental model of what elements are in `var` when it finally gets tested.

Comment: `let(:foo) { bar(var) }` is useless here, you can simply remove it and call `var` directly.